# Isotope & Media Queries

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, jquery-isotope, fluid

Absolutely pulling my hair out on this one.  There seems to be no black and white solution offered on [GitHub](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/271) - which is strange, since it seems like a fairly simple concept.  Perhaps I just don't get it.

Basically, I am trying to create a **fluid** and **responsive** portfolio - using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to filter the items.  The filtering works fine, the 4 columns are totally fluid and everything looks great when you resize the window.

**HOWEVER**, for mobile and tablet layouts, I simply need to adapt from a **4-column** layout to a **2-column** layout.

I tried this:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    var $container = $('#thumbs');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
       },
    });

    // initialize Isotope
    $container.isotope({
      // options...
      resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
      // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
      masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 4 },
    });

    // update columnWidth on window resize
    $(window).smartresize(function(){
        $container.isotope({
            // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 4 }
        });
    });

// My attempt at using media queries to change 'columnWidth'
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 768) {
            $container.isotope( {
                // update columnWidth to half of container width
                masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 2 }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Didn't work :(

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work to set your number of columns. Then you just divide with `columns`.

```
var columns;

// set column number
setColumns();

// rerun function when window is resized 
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  setColumns();
});

// the function to decide the number of columns
function setColumns() {
  if($(window).width() <= 768) {
    columns = 2;
  } else {
    columns = 4;
  }
}
```

Comment: I realised why mine wasn't working. In the `$container.isotope({` function I was using `masonry: {columnWidth: $container.width() / 4}` instead of just `columns: 4`. Sorted. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Salmonface I have the same problem, I cant seem to change the layout to two columns when the window shrinks.. how did you fix that? `var $container = $('#filter_container');
      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.element',
      resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3 }
    
      });
   // update columnWidth on window resize
  $(window).smartresize(function(){
    $container.isotope({
   // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
   masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 3 }
    });
  });`

Comment: Hi @Grundizer I fixed it by using a jQuery media query:     `$(window).smartresize(function(){ if ($(window).width() < 768) { $container.isotope({ columns: 2 });} if ($(window).width() > 768) { $container.isotope({ columns: 3 });}});` However, my grid is fluid, so my column widths and margins are based on percentages - which obviously requires updating in your css via a media query when you adapt the number of columns.

Comment: See the portfolio section of my [website](http://nassimdonald.co.uk/) for an example - sorry the code isn't very well organised.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a slightly nicer way where you can still use css media queries. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20270911/1010892

Hope that helps!!